# Write live text in a picture ( Live render of text in a picture )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an **image** and a **text field** (input).

I would like to know if possible, when I **insert** text in the text field, I would like to **see** the text in the **image** (live).

An example found in a website: https://us.maisondesabre.com/products/iphone-11-pro?variant=31088001286223

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Can it be done in javascript / jquery?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Yes. You can use a transparent background overlay on your image element, on the overlay you can initialize an empty text element, then user enters something in the text field, it's mapping to the text element on the overlay. Also you can dynamically change font color based on color selection

Comment: Yes this can be done, in a nut shell.... Simply create a right side DIV, then place your form on the left div. Set these in a flex box container. Then add a background image of your phone and center your text in a child div in your left side parent div. Get the tags ID using JS and set you innnerHTML to the form inputs value.